# nvd3.js remove line from line plus bar chart

Tags: charts, nvd3.js

I would like to add simple bar chart to my site. I am already using nvd3.js [line plus bar chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html). Is there a way how to simply remove a line or should I use another graph (eg. [discrete bar chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html)) and try to put data there so it looks like simple basic bar chart?
I am trying to avoid getting another library for graphs. That would add extra files to my website. Also I think using same graph library will be better for user experience (same colors, tooltips, ...).

Edit1: I was [told](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/865#issuecomment-78086178) to use **historicalBarChart** or **multiBarChart** to get simple bar chart functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a simple bar chart, I would recommend using the [discrete bar chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html).

If for some reason you **HAVE** to use the line plus bar chart and **DO NOT** want the line, simply handle it in the JSON data when you pass into the chart :

```
[{ 
      "key" : "AAA" , 
      "bar": true,
      "color": "#abc",
      "values" : [....]},
{ 
      "key" : "BBB" , 
      "bar": true,
      "color": "#def",
      "values" : [....]}
]
```

Have a look at this [sample JSON](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBarData.json) that's used for a line plus bar chart.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works. I have tried `"bar": true,` before, but it did not show graph. I tried to upgrade my nvd3.js and it shows properly now. My pie charts on that page disappeared (hope it will be easy fix). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Hm, easy fix indeed. exampleData() change its structure - does not contain key and returns values directly.